# The equivalent of tf.contrib.image.transform in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

What is the equivalent of `tf.contrib.image.transform` in `tensorflow 2.0`? When I use the `tf_upgrade_v2` conversion script, I get the error:

```
ERROR: Using member tf.contrib.image.transform in deprecated module tf.contrib. tf.contrib.image.transform cannot be converted automatically. tf.contrib will not be distributed with TensorFlow 2.0, please consider an alternative in non-contrib TensorFlow, a community-maintained repository such as tensorflow/addons, or fork the required code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent. Some of the ops are implemented in the tensorflow addons though which is only available in Linux not Windows for now.

Here is the link to tensorflow addones:
https://github.com/tensorflow/addons

Here is the link to one of their image ops which is similar to tf.contrib.image.transform:
https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/docs/tutorials/image_ops.ipynb

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

As [said by Amir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58294964/11543584) this seems to not be part of the new API.

Maybe you can look at the [TensorFlow Graphics](https://github.com/tensorflow/graphics) library. I did not find any equivalent of `transform` for the moment, but I think that such implementation can fit in this library.